# shell variable not be replace with actually value

Tags: shell

try to get string from configuration file, e.g.

```
ORACLE_BASE=/a/b
while read line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ^ORACLE_HOME ]]; then
       ORACLE_HOME=`echo $line | sed -e 's/ORACLE_HOME=//g'`
       ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_HOME
       echo "ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_HOME"
    fi
done < ./conf/setupSM.conf
```

output like:

> ORACLE_HOME=${ORACLE_BASE}/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1

But the expecting output should be:

> ORACLE_HOME=/a/b/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1

but ${ORACLE_BASE} still not be replaced by the value, what should to do to make it work

Comment: What does the conf file look like?

Comment: In your example code, you set the variable ORACLE_BASE, but you don't use it anywhere.

Comment: In addition, your statement `ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_HOME` is redundant. It just assigns a variable to itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is only a single pass of variable interpolation. A variable containing another variable in its value will not be expanded.

In your limited scenario, you could consider using `eval`; or if it's just a single variable which may or may not be present, do the interpolation in your `sed` script:

```
ORACLE_HOME=`echo "$line" |
    sed -e 's/ORACLE_HOME=//' \
        -e "s/\${\?ORACLE_BASE}\?/$ORACLE_BASE/"`
```

Note that the `/g` flag serves no useful purpose here (it wuld only be useful if you needed to replace multiple occurrences on the same line) and the proper quoting of `"$line"`. You should also consider using lowercase for your own variable names, to avoid having them clash with system variables.

The shell loop isn't really necessary or useful, either; I would refactor the `sed` script to loop over the entire file, and print only the last occurrence. This is not hard to do in `sed`, either, but I'd go with Awk, which is slightly less of a write-only language.

```
ORACLE_HOME=$(awk -F= -v b="$ORACLE_BASE" '$1 == "ORACLE_HOME" { o=$2 }
    END { sub("${?ORACLE_BASE}?", b, o); print o }' ./conf/setupSM.conf)
```

Answer (score 0):

When `./conf/setupSM.conf` has lines like

```
ORACLE_HOME=${ORACLE_BASE}/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1
```

(without spaces or in double quotes)
and you want ORACLE_BASE to be evaluated to your current settings, source your conf file (with a dot):

```
ORACLE_BASE=/a/b
. ./conf/setupSM.conf
echo "ORACLE_HOME=${ORACLE_HOME}"
```

This should give

```
ORACLE_HOME=/a/b/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1
```